# Sanitizing raw SQL string Java JDBCTemplate

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

My team is using a query builder in frontend which builds the where clause portion of an SQL and it is passed to the backend to be ran for a preview query function,

What I am trying to do now is prevent SQL Injection as the forming of the full sql has this concept:

`String sql = baseSQL + " WHERE " + whereClause;`

Code is executed using JDBCTemplate:

`List<Map<String, String>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForLists(sql);`

Using parameterized query is not possible as we are not able to predict the possible column it will be filtered against, what would be the best way to ensure that this is safe from SQL Injection?

Comment: The safest way would be for the backend to parse the WHERE clause and verify that the syntax matches a WHERE clause.  No semicolons, no DELETE, whatever else you think of.

Answer (score 0):

replace your `jdbcTemplate` with `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`

That will save you in general from SQL injection. Check [spring-doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html)

Here is an example from [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate)

```
String SELECT_BY_ID = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE FIRST_NAME = :firstName";

SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(employee);
return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
  SELECT_BY_ID, namedParameters, Integer.class);
```